# How to create user in UAA using rest api?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, cloudfoundry-uaa

Could anyone please help me the way to create user in UAA by consuming rest api?

I have refered below url, but I am bit confused about the token to pass. I don't have token to pass for create user request.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#create-a-user-post-users

Please help me with sample user create request.

Comment: This tutorial is a good source of information: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: Thanks @ccit-spence... Yeah, I have gone through it.. But I am trying to create an user without passing the bearer token. is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: You need to get a token first: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#id16